# htaccess rewrite - prevent multiple redirects

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The following regex works perfectly except for under the condition when the user goes to `examplesite1.com/site1`. When this happens the page fails because of multiple redirects in which it continues to add the `request=site1` query to the URL. I thought that adding `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` would fix this issue however that seemed to not be the case.

This setup is for a multi-domain website. There are three folders site1, site2, and shared. There are also rewrite rules for site2 and shared that are not shown as they do not effect this issue.

```
# if the resource exists in site1 return it to the user
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} examplesite1.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site1/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1 [QSA,L]

# no file found, send URI to CMS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

complete .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Disallow browsing file directories
Options -Indexes 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#remove the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} examplesite1.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site1/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} examplesite2.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site2/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site2/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/shared/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shared/$1 [QSA,L]

# resources not to be public are sent to CMS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (\.inc\.|\.tpl$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]

# no resource found, send URI to CMS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extra condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} examplesite1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site1/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site1/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

What looks like may be happening here is that you need to prevent a redirect from happening after one of your other rules get applied. Try adding this *right below* `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Sadly that made a rewrite loop in the root directory. Also, after reverted it back it cached the rewrite so I can't test other options, I'm not sure why that's happening.

Comment: @michaellindahl rewrites don't get cached, redirects do (by your browser), unless you're accessing this through a proxy server. If there are other rules elsewhere, obviously those are part of the overall problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've added my complete .htaccess file if that helps, but I believe I abstracted it well. Are these redirects defaulting to 301? Can I changed them to be 302 without showing them to the end user? How do I stop my browser (Safari) from caching the redirects.